# flutter_localizations package is not converting the numbers to currency values based on format type

Tags: flutter, dart

I added flutter_localizations library in my project and followed the steps as per
[official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization) to convert the number to currency but no result. I added below code to my arb file

```
  "amountWithCompactCurrency" : "Current Budget of application : {amount}",
  "@amount" : {
   "description" : "Amount with compact currency",
   "placeholders" : {
     "amount" : {
      "type" : "int",
      "format" : "compactCurrency",
      "optionalParameters": {
              "decimalDigits": 2
            }
     }
  }
```

```
var amount = 800000;
${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.amountWithCompactCurrency(amount)}
```

But still, it is showing numbers only

[image]

I did flutter clean, added intl package as well, but no luck.

Comment: Did you run `flutter gen-l10n` to regenerate Dart files from ARBs?

Comment: yes, but facing this issue =>> 

Because l10n.yaml exists, the options defined there will be used instead.
To use the command line arguments, delete the l10n.yaml file in the Flutter project.

Comment: what you quoted is not an issue. It's just a note to you. Nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: Yes my apology , but if I delete that YAML file it is throwing error and not generating the locale files =>>  Error: Error when reading '.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

Comment: Why do you delete the `l10n.yaml`? Don't you want to have a place to configure your localization? Anyway, when you have `synthetic-package` set to true (this is the default), you need to have `generate: true` under `flutter:` in your `pubspec.yaml`